# How to merge two tables without id and with different number of columns in MySQL

Tags: mysql

I have two tables with different columns. Tables doesn't have id column. They have the same number of rows. I want to merge them in new table. I've tried to do this like this:

```
CREATE TABLE test_3_cut_dest as 
 SELECT * FROM test_3_cut_ 
  UNION 
 SELECT * FROM test_3_cut
```

but got error:

> each UNION query must have the same number of columns

I want to know how achieve merging of two tables with different number of columns without specifying list of columns?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Union requires that all participating selects yield matching record sets, meaning same number of columns and compatible data types for each column.

As for your question, you can use **placeholders** wherever there is a mismatch. For instance:

```
SELECT Col1, Col2, 'DUMMYVALUE'
  FROM Table1
UNION ALL
SELECT Col1, Col2, Col3
  FROM Table2 ;
```

Now, if table1 has 3 textual columns and table2 has 6 textual columns, you can go with:

```
SELECT * , 'DUMMYVALUE1','DUMMYVALUE2','DUMMYVALUE3'
  FROM Table1
UNION ALL
SELECT *
  FROM Table2 ;
```

Answer (score 1):

I don't think it works with select * when it comes to not knowing how many columns each table has. The best way to do it is like this:

```
SELECT A, B, C, D, E, F, G, H FROM test_3_cut_
UNION
SELECT A, B, NULL AS C, NULL AS D, NULL AS E, NULL AS ...  FROM test_3_cut
```

I've done it like this considering test_3_cut has fewer columns than test_3_cut_

Answer (score 0):

Union works like this:

```
Select column1 from table1
union
select column1 from table2
```

Number of columns must be same in both Select Queries.

Comment: Ok. But I want to know how achieve merging of two tables with different number of columns without specifying columns

Answer (score 0):

You have to select from the two tables the same set of columns. If one of the tables has more columns, you can either select only the columns they share or select a fake value for the missing column from the table that has less.

Example

```
Table1
col1 | col2 | col3

Table2
col1 | col2
```

You can do this

```
select col1, col2 from Table1
union all
select col1, col2 from Table2
```

or this

```
select col1, col2, col3 from Table1
union all
select col1, col2, '' from Table2
```